# ClickListener outside the GUI

Tags: java, user-interface, events, event-handling, onclicklistener

Is it possible to have a programm (f.ex. JavaFX GUI) to run in the background and still have the clickEvents active? f.ex. play a sound if you click 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can refer this SO answer [How to detect mouseclick event outside the stage and close it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36430347/how-to-detect-mouseclick-event-outside-the-stage-and-close-it)

Basically you need to register a listener with `stage.focusedProperty()` and call your function if the focused property changes to false.

**Modified code**

```
    import javafx.application.Application;
    import javafx.scene.Scene;
    import javafx.scene.control.Button;
    import javafx.scene.control.Label;
    import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
    import javafx.stage.Modality;
    import javafx.stage.Stage;

    public class CloseWindowOnClickOutside extends Application {

        @Override
        public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
            Button showPopup = new Button("Show popup");
            showPopup.setOnAction(e -> {
                Stage popup = new Stage();
                Scene scene = new Scene(new Label("Popup"), 120, 40);
                popup.setScene(scene);
                popup.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
                popup.initOwner(primaryStage);
                popup.focusedProperty().addListener((obs, wasFocused, isNowFocused) -> {
                  //if the click is outside the stage  
                    if (! isNowFocused) {
                        myFunction();
                    }
                });
                popup.show();
            });

            StackPane root = new StackPane(showPopup);
            Scene scene = new Scene(root, 350, 120);
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            launch(args);
        }

        public void myFunction(){
         //handle the event here
        }
    }
```